# Get absolute url to file in a directory on a server with php

Tags: php

I am using this code to get url to some folder on the server:

```
print_r(str_replace("\\","/",dirname(__FILE__)));
```

This returns for example (this is the **dir** in next code example)

```
/nas/content/live/tcshop/wp-content/uploads/mvp-file-dir/audio/music/m034/
```

Then I use php DirectoryIterator to read files from this directory.

I use this code:

```
$protocol = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] !== 'off' || 
$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443) ? "https://" : "http://";

if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == "localhost"){
    define('SITE_URL', $protocol . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/');
    define('SITEPATH', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/');
}
else{ 
    define('SITE_URL', $protocol . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
    define('SITEPATH', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
}

$dir = $_REQUEST['dir'];

$media = array();
$i = 0;

$di = new DirectoryIterator($dir);
    foreach ($di as $fileinfo) {
        $path_info = pathinfo($fileinfo->getPathname());
        if(isset($path_info['extension'])){
            if(in_array(strtolower($path_info['extension']), $type)){
                $fn = $fileinfo->getPathname();
                $media[] = array( 
                    "SITE_URL" => SITE_URL, 
                    "SITEPATH" => SITEPATH, 
                    "fullpath" => SITE_URL.'/'.path2url(realpath($path_info['dirname'])).'/'.$path_info['basename'],  
                    "basename" => $path_info['basename'], 
                    "extension" => $path_info['extension'],
                    "dirname" => realpath($path_info['dirname']),
                    "filename" => $path_info['filename']
                ); 
                $i++;  
                if($i==$limit) break;
            }
        }
    }

echo json_encode($media);

function path2url($dirname) {
    return str_replace(SITEPATH, '', str_replace('\\', '/', $dirname));
}
```

The problem is when I want to get full absolute url to the path on the server.

**fullpath** returns

```
https://some-domain.com/nas/content/live/tcshop/wp-content/uploads/mvp-file-dir/audio/music/m034/some-file.mp3
```

While the actual url to some-file is

```
https://some-domain.com/wp-content/uploads/mvp-file-dir/audio/music/m034/some-file.mp3
```

So you can see part of the url not correct and I get invalid file url. Is there a way to get right url?

Comment: so just cut out the document root from the path?

Comment: What's the value of `SITEPATH`?

Comment: @shingo. - SITEPATH: "/nas/wp/www/sites/tcsdevelop"
SITE_URL: "https://tcsdevelop.wpengine.com". Please help me solve this. It has to be dynamic, otherwise I would just hardcode this.

Comment: @YourCommonSense - It has to be dynamic, otherwise I would just hardcode this. My question was how do I know I need to cut out this part? So please give me reliable way to get direct link to file on the server because as you can see from my code, its not working.